# Ho to save all output images in CNN into a file

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch, visualization, conv-neural-network

I am running a CNN network and want to save output images (testing data) into a file. I made a function for visualization and saving. I am calling function in test_loader to save each of output images into a file from `1` to `100` which is total of testing data. I can just save the last output image in a test_loader loop. I am not sure how to save all `100` images.

Plot function is :

```
def stress_plot(y, y_hat):
 
    y_hat = y_hat[0,0].cpu().detach().numpy()
    y = y[0,0].cpu().detach().numpy()
    
    y_hat = denorm(y_hat)
    y = denorm(y)
    
    plt.figure()
    sns.heatmap(y, cmap='jet', square=True, xticklabels=False,
                yticklabels=False)
    plt.text(200,-20, "Real Stress", fontsize = 15, color='Black')
    plt.figure()
    sns.heatmap(y_hat, cmap='jet', square=True, xticklabels=False,
                yticklabels=False)
    plt.text(200,-20, "Predicted Stress", fontsize = 15, color='Black')
    plt.save('output/%d.png' % i)
    plt.show()
```

Call the function in test_loader:

```
model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in test_loader:
            x_test_batch, y_test_batch = data[0].to(device, 
                dtype=torch.float), data[1].to(device, dtype=torch.float)

            y_test_pred = model(x_test_batch)
            mse_val_loss = criterion(y_test_batch, y_test_pred, x_test_batch, mse)
            stress_plot( y_test_batch, y_test_pred)
```

Comment: I think it is saving all files with same filenames, so every time old file is getting overwritten with new file. And when program finish executing. you can only see last file.

Comment: Yes, but how can I save all files?

Comment: try something which make filename different for every input file. Like append a counter to output file name. Initialize counter to 0 initially, and increment it with every loop.